# How to make a Spring's custom scope that share information between two or more sessions?

Tags: java, spring, session, grails

We have an application that contains a chat. We are using the Node.JS's IO Socket to make the push to the client. The client, when authenticated, is connecting to a room with his/her id as identifier of the room. We did it because there're some singletons that push some notifications to the client, independent of his/her session. The chat's spring bean is SessionScoped.
The problem we're facing happens when the same client login in the system with two different browsers. Two sessions are created, so there's two spring beans of the chat operating. Since both beans push to the room identified by the user id, in the client side, the same message arrives two times. The number of duplicated messages increases with the number of browsers.

So, I wanna create a custom scope for the Spring. This scope must be shared between all the clients logged in with the same login and must be destroyed as soon as all the sessions logged in with this login be destroyed.

I think this scope will need a map with all the sessions for each login and it'll need to listen for the destruction of these sessions. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why not change the identifier of the chat? Two different browsers should be handled as two unique user chat, or do like GMail, and keep just one session and force logoff of the other.

Comment: I would like to save resources. If a creat a chat instance per session (even that it's the same user), I'll spend more resources of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

I created a spring's singleton bean that has a Map created with MapMaker of Guava. The map has a weak value (more about weak references here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references). Then I have a spring's session bean. This session bean ask the singleton for an instance for the chat passing the id of the client. The singleton, verify if there's something in the map. If it doesn't have, it creates a new chat instance, puts in the map and returns it. The session bean maintains a reference for this chat instance. If the user login in a different browser, a new session bean will do the same. This time, it'll get the instance saved in the map. When there's no more session beans with references to the chat instance, it'll be garbage collected, since the map has a weak reference for it.